# how to use variable in md file with hugo

Tags: hugo

I'm using hugo.
I want to use i18n in content/contact.md.
However, I can't use variables and such in the same way as I use html under normal layouts.
How can I do this?

■content/contact.md

```
---
draft: true
---
<div class="app_static_contents app_static_contents-form">
  <div class="app_static_contents-form_box flex-l justify-between items-center center">
    <h3 class="">{{ i18n "inquiry" }}</h3>
    <div class="app_static_contents-form_link">
      <a class="btn" target="_blank" href="{{ .forms.inquiry.url }}" >{{ i18n "fromHere" }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your HTML above into your/a template, then you can use il8n. If for some reason you don't do that fix, then use shortcodes to reference the partial that has your form in it. If for some reason that fix isn't to be done, then create a shortcode that passes a text param that calls a partial that uses the param to call an il8n token.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Hugo [shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/). You can also use [markdown render hooks](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#markdown-render-hooks) if the content is an image, link or heading.

Is there a reason you're writing HTML for this static page directly in your markdown? You would be better off creating a dedicated layout for your contact page in layouts. Then you can use the i18n features in your HTML without worrying about shortcodes.